# convergence of the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}E_k(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define $E_0(x)=x$, $E_1(x)=e^{E_0(x)}=e^x$, $E_2(x)=e^{E_1(x)}=e^{e^x}$, $\cdots$, $E_{n+1}(x)=e^{E_n(x)}$. For which values of $ x $ the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}E_k(x)$ converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\exp$ is strictly increasing and positive so  $E_1>0$ then $E_{2}>1$ and by induction:
$E_n>1$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty}E_n\ne0$ hence the given series is divergent for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** By a direct induction, you have
$$
E_n(x)\geq 1, \quad n=2,3,4,\ldots,\quad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$ and your series $\displaystyle  \sum E_n(x)$ is divergent since the general term does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Actually, $E_1(x) = e^x < 1$ for $x < 0$. But the conclusion still follows.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 You are right, I've fixed it. Thanks.